# Error when pasting from jGrasp to OneNote then back to jGrasp - Java

Tags: java

This is the first time I post something to Stack Over Flow.  So, I'm having a techinical problem when I am copying my code from OneNote.

So, what I do is I watch the video lectures my professor has on YouTube, and I also create a copy of his code on jGrasp on my Mac, then I copy it into OneNote 2016 to store it as future reference.  Well, the other day I tried to copy the code  back into jGrasp from OneNote, and when I try to compile it, I get the following error, about 15 times:

MathFun.java:2: error: illegal character: '\u00a0'
{   
  ^

I have found a way around this - if I copy into TextEdit first, which doesn't have formating, and then into OneNote, and then back into jGrasp, it works.

So,

jGrasp --> OneNote --> jGrasp

= Error

jGrasp --> TextEdit --> OneNote --> jGrasp

!= Error (No error)

I can use this work around, but it would be way nice if I didn't have to retype all the code I have already written just to run it in jGrasp again.  Any susjestions?

Thanks.

P.S.:
This is my code from this example:

```
public class MathFun
{   
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

      System.out.println("Test.");

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That character is a non-breaking space, so probably OneNote is substituting it for ordinary spaces. Try "Edit" > "Paste Special" in jGRASP and see if a plain text paste will avoid this. Otherwise, you could find and select one of the non-breaking spaces (looks like a space, shows code 160 in the message bar) then do a Ctrl-F and replace with regular spaces.